# changing the color of a textview using a spinner in another activity

Tags: android

I have two activities activity1 and activity2. in activity2 I have a spinner which is populated by several colors and what I want to do is when I select a color in the spinner it changes the color of a textview inside activity1 when I do it inside the same activity it works otherwise it doesn't any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Shared Preferences like this in your "settings"

```
//create SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("nameYourSharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//get what color is selected from spinner and add it to SharedPreferences as a String for example
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("color", "red");
    editor.apply();
```

In your "MainActivity" get the color like this

```
//create SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("nameYourSharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//this will return the color you saved before or "defaultValue"...
String userSelectedColor = sharedPreferences.getString("color", "defaultValue");

//code to change the color wherever you want
if(userSelectedColor.equals("defaultValue"))
{
    //don't change anything
}
else if(userSelectedColor.equals("red"))
{
    //change color to red
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. You got everything right yes I want to make it permanent but i didn't get to how to incorporate shared preferences with the spinner

Answer (score 0):

**Use this intent method in your Activity1**

```
 Intent i=new Intent(Edit_News.this,Activity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i,2);
```

**In Activity2 **

*select color in your spinner and use this after selecting color and pass your color code in this*

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("color",#fffff);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
```

**Now in your activity1 when activity2 finish this method will call**

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, result);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 2:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Bundle bundle = result.getExtras();
            int    colorcod= bundle.getDouble("color");

       mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colorcod));
            }

            break;
            }
}
```